# Looping through array and grouping every nth row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Good Evening everyone!

Question regarding lists,

If I have a list with N elements - how do I index through the array sending every N rows to a new list.

```
class _TVRequestGET_######:
def __init__(self):
    self.TVRequestURL = "############" 
    self.emptyArray   = []
def __GET__(self):
    dataStream      = requests.get(######().TVRequestURL).text
    regexStrSym     = 'target="_blank">(\w+)</a><'
    regexStrDT      = '>(\d{10,20}.00)<'
    findSymbols     = re.findall(regexStrSym, dataStream)
    findDateTme     = re.findall(regexStrDT , dataStream)
    return __dataStream__
```

When ran findDateTme returns an array of 188 elements - every two values are related so I need to be able to grab `findDateTme[i], findDateTme[i+1]` then when the second group is created `findDateTme[i+2], findDateTme[i+3]`the final array would be 94 elements in the form of `[a,b]`

This was my attempt at it but I run into list index out of range and thats because when i = 189, i will then equal 189 - 1 = 188 which puts the index out of range

```
for i in range(len(findDateTme)):
    i = i + 1
    self.emptyArray = [findDateTme[i], findDateTme[i-1]]

return self.emptyArray
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shorthand, you can do

```
for x,y in zip(findDateTme[::2], findDateTme[1::2]):
    self.emptyArray.append([x,y])
return self.emptyArray
```

Also you need to append to your array, not replace it on every iteration of the loop.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer - many thanks

Answer (score 2):

how about try:

```
for i in range(0, len(findDateTme) - 1, 2):
    self.emptyArray = [findDateTme[i], findDateTme[i + 1]]
```

when you using for loop, do not modify i or other index variable inside the loop, only do this in while loop.

hope can help.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!